# In rails, how can I import a user's facebook contacts when they sign up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook

I have a signup form, and I wanted to make it so that they have the option of recommending this signup to all their friends in facebook.

Is there a rails API/gem for doing this?

Is there an appropriate name for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have two options:

- popup a javascript before submitting the form to prompt the user wether he wants to share it with friends. You will use the js api http://github.com/facebook/connect-js (see the dialog section). This solution would avoid doing server side connection to the facebook api
- Have a look a the [Facebooker](http://github.com/mmangino/facebooker) gem to do a [stream_publish](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish)

Comment: Those don't import contacts. I'd like to import the emails of their contacts. And then popup my own JS API that would allow them to select who they want to email..

Comment: well that's another question, but you can import them via http://facebooker.rubyforge.org/classes/Facebooker/User.html#M000378

Comment: What do people typically do with them when they get them ? :D

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the [Extended permissions documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions), you don't get access to the email addresses of a Facebook user's friends (search for `email` and note the second column reads *not available*). If that's what you're trying to achieve, it's almost certainly not possible, without the user contacting each friend and asking them to visit your app (which I would imagine would have quite a low take-up, if only through inertia).